# Determine the asymptotic behaviour of the following integral

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, asymptotics, integration-by-parts

$$I(x)=\int^{\infty}_{x}\exp(-t^{4}) dt \text{ as }x \rightarrow \infty$$

I have in my notes that:

\begin{align}I(x)&=\dfrac{-1}{4}\int^{\infty}_{x}\dfrac{1}{t^3}\dfrac{d}{dt}(e^{-t^{4}}) dt\\\\
&=\dfrac{-1}{4} \left[\dfrac{e^{-t^4}}{t^3}\right]^{\infty}_{x}-\dfrac{3}{4}\int^{\infty}_{x}\dfrac{1}{t^4}e^{-t^4}dt\\\\
& = \dfrac{e^{-x^4}}{4x^3}-\dfrac{3}{4}\int^{\infty}_{x}\dfrac{1}{t^4}e^{-t^4}dt\end{align}

I understand that to obtain the asymptotic approximation of the function we need to integrate by parts but could someone explain the above steps.

Comment: Which step are you missing, precisely ?

Comment: to you mean $$-\infty$$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that we know how to integrate $t^3 e^{-t^4}$ by just substituting $u=t^4$. So you force in a factor of $t^3$:

$$\int_x^\infty e^{-t^4} dt = \int_x^\infty \frac{1}{t^3} (t^3 e^{-t^4}) dt$$

and then integrate by parts from there, with $dv=t^3 e^{-t^4} dt$. In the end you get a new integral. You still can't actually calculate it, but it decays faster as $x \to \infty$ than your original integral (because it has a factor of $\frac{1}{t^4}$ in the integrand).